# Python why we cant random decimal values

Tags: python, random, decimal

My Code:

```
import random
randomlist = []
for i in range(0,100):
    n = random.randint(1.0,2.0)
    randomlist.append(n)
print(randomlist)
```

From Above Code :

```
n = random.randint(1.0,2.0)
```

Its Correct

But When

```
n = random.randint(0.1,1.0)
n = random.randint(0.001,1.001)
```

Gives An Error

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py",
> line 31, in <module>
>     start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py",
> line 30, in start
>     exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)   File "<string>", line 4, in <module>   File
> "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/random.py",
> line 248, in randint
>     return self.randrange(a, b+1)   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/random.py",
> line 212, in randrange
>     raise ValueError("non-integer arg 1 for randrange()") ValueError: non-integer arg 1 for randrange()

[Program finished]
```

How Its Possible?

Comment: Why do you want to pass non-`int` arguments to `randint` at all?

Comment: Do you know what the definition of an integer is? The only integer between 0.001 and 1.001 is 1. There is no integer between 0.1 and 1.0, unless you include 1.0, in which case the integer is 1. So, what you're asking Python to do doesn't make sense, hence the error.

Answer (score 5):

[`Randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) gives a random integer
An integer is a non-decimal number.

Just use [`random.uniform`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform)